# How to work when the folder \\appdata\local is locked because of security policy?

Tags: windows, virus, corporate-policy

My admin has set the group policy so that no executable can be run on the folder \appdata\local (because this is a common place for virus to start infecting).

As a consequence, my electron applications can't be run anymore unless I move them to the Desktop, and my gradle builds plugin won't run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using [Turbo.net](http://turbo.net). My application run on a containerized and isolated environment without touching the forbidden folders (it is basically Docker but for Windows).